# Fresco Issuses : Image is not display in SimpleDraweeView

Tags: android, fresco

I am loading image from local path, image is available in particular path but its not shown in SDV if i am getting below log

```
D/skia: --- decoder->decode returned false
D/skia: --- decoder->decode returned false
```

I am getting this log multiple times, i am setting image from adapter

Comment: Please provide more information: the code where you configure the SimpleDraweeView, information about the image (size on disk, format, width, height). If possible, provide a link to the image. Furthermore, show more logcat output (as this error can occur as a consequence of insufficient memory).

Comment: I am configure my SDV in adapter, my image config code is int MAX_HEAP_SIZE = (int) Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory();
String IMAGE_PIPELINE_CACHE_DIR = "imagepipeline_cache";
int MAX_DISK_CACHE_SIZE = 40 * ByteConstants.MB;
int MAX_MEMORY_CACHE_SIZE = MAX_HEAP_SIZE / 4;MemoryCacheParams(MAX_MEMORY_CACHE_SIZE,Integer.MAX_VALUE, MAX_MEMORY_CACHE_SIZE,Integer.MAX_VALUE,Integer.MAX_VALUE);